# c# how to measure used memory from referenced method

Tags: c#, dll, stack-overflow

I've written a program that splits an XML into a lot of smaller XMLs and for performance reasons this program keeps all XML writers open at the same time and calls the relevant methods recursively. Also all this is nested in zip and xml readers and writers. When a lot of writers are open at the same time a stackoverflow exception happens and since these can't be caught I try to throw an exception in my code if too much memory is used. This works fine as a stand-alone application, but the used memory is reported incorrectly from the same method when used as a reference.

I wrote the following code that is called each recursion:

```
            var performance = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            var available = performance.NextValue()/10;
            var memory = 0.0;

            using (Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                memory = proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / (1024 * 1024);
            }
            
            if(memory / available > maxMemoryUsageFactor)
            {
                throw new Exception("Memory usage is too high.");
            }
```

This seems to do the trick when I run the program as a application. Typically on my workstation I will get a value of 328 MB for available memory (please note that I devide the MB as gotten from PerformanceCounter by 10, which makes it correpond with the debugger from Visual Studio, but is kinda odd). For maxMemoryUsageFactor I use 0.8, so that I can do a safe rollback of all the streams.

However, the code is intended to be used as a reference (.dll) in another application, and when I use it as such it seems be able to use roughly the same amount of memory, but only reports the memory used by the main application, not by the referenced method. At the point where it normally will report about 75% of memory usage, none of the metrics available in the process reports over 30%:

> Initiating Chained writer 964 of 964 | current memory (MB): 58 of 300,9(19,2755072038829%) |  PagedMemorySize64:58 NonpagedSystemMemorySize64:0 VirtualMemorySize64:4709 WorkingSet64:69 PagedSystemMemorySize64:0 PeakPagedMemorySize64:58

I assume that this has something to do with either the accessibility of the memory used by the reference (since Visual studio also shows only about 60MB in it's performance chart now and in the stand alone version 328MB), or lag in memory reporting, but I have no idea how and why.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I feel the need to point out that XML writers and serializers and stuff like that do not get stored in the stack, they get stored in the heap. Usually a stackoverflow exception is caused by a logic error (e.g. infinite recursion), unless you have an unusually high number of structs as local variables.

Comment: @JohnWu I took a few memory snapshots and the writers are indeed in the heap. The heap usage looks roughly the same for the referenced class as the stand alone application.

Comment: If the writers are on the heap, and you're getting a stack overflow exception, then the writers' memory use isn't the problem.

Comment: My problem is not so much what causes the stackoverflow exception though, but how to detect beforehand that memory is running out.